# Same solutions, different results on Codechef (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

https://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT/ - This is the problem to be solved

https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/9110492 - My solution in Java (implemented Comparison sort)

https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8599514 - Some other persons solution in Java (he also implemented comparison sort)

When I submit my solution, I get TLE (Time Limit Exceeded), but the other solution gets AC.

What could be the possible reasons for this difference ?

Note : If the solutions are different, please let me know the differences and areas of improvement in code.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that meets the eye is the usage of (own implementation) `FastScanner` class in "other" solution. Just reading data from System.in and not waiting (like your code does!) for complete lines given in System.in.

I'd guess your solution is waiting for the line to end for your `BufferedReader` to proceed - but given the test input it never does.

By calling BufferedReader.readLine() you block until

a) EOF is read (will not happen with StdIn unless intentionally) or

b) a line (including valid line separator char(s) for that platform) has been read.

Your competitor just read from `System.in` into a large `byte[]` - as much information as was available at that time. So it might be save to assume that there just **is** no linebreak in `System.in` so your code is stuck.

The input in the assignment specifically shows no line break after the last int. So that's probably where you're waiting for more input.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain in a bit more detail that what is the problem in using BufferedReader for accepting inputs for the given input format.. Your feedback might help me understand the concepts better !! Thanks

Comment: Edited my question to explain more.